# How to find out if file transfer is going on by a TeamViewer connection?

Tags: teamviewer

My PC has to be connected via TeamViewer several times. If you drag n drop files then, a file transfer message box appears and hence I can see that the person connected to my PC is transferring files.

**QUESTION:** I am wondering if there is a way to find out if the person connected to my PC is transferring files (from my PC to his) using **File Transfer dialogue box** (as shown in the screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a question for TeamViewer support or their forums.